# React-router-dom displays nothing when using 'Route'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

I am trying to render an ultra-simple webpage using react-routing-dom lib. Here is my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './nav.js';
import Shop from './shop.js';
import About from './about.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Nav />
    <Router>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<About />} />
      <Route exact path='/shop' element={<Shop />} />
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

using this, I run `npm start` and expect that the `<Nav />` and `<About />` components render at `http://localhost:3000`. Instead, the screen is completely blank. There are no warnings, errors, etc.; it's a clean build. Not even the `<Nav />` component that is ***outside*** the entire Router block is rendered!

The plot thickens: when I build and run the following, all three components render.

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './nav.js';
import Shop from './shop.js';
import About from './about.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Nav />
    <Router>
      <About />
      <Shop />
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

From this, I think its safe to assume that `<Route />` is the problem.

react-router-dom seems to change a lot in a relatively short amount of time, so there is a lot of outdated info. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I see missing is the `Routes` component wrapping the `Route` components. You imported `Routes` but don't appear to have used it. All `Route` components **must** be rendered into a `Routes` component (*or another `Route` if nesting*). Without the `Routes` you *should* be seeing the error `A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.`

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<About />} />
    <Route exact path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-displays-nothing-when-using-route]

Comment: That worked like a charm! I had not tried Router AND Routes together. I think that may have been the only thing I did not try...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed react-router-dom version 6. for version 6 you must wrap up all 'Route' inside a "Routes".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).